# Capture the S3 file download start and end times and other details

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to expose an API (preferably using AWS API gateway/ Lambda/Go) to the users.

Using this API, the users can download a binary file from S3 bucket.

I want to capture the metrics like, which user has started download of the file, the time at which the file download had started and finished.

I want to record these timestamps in DynamoDB.

S3 has support for Events for creating/modifying/deleting files, so I can write a lambda function for these events.

But S3 doesn't seems to have support for read actions ( e.g. download a file)

I am thinking to write a Lambda function, which will be invoked when the user calls the API to download the file. In the lambda, I want to record the timestamp, read the file into a buffer, encode it and then send it as as base64 encoded response to the client.

Let me know if there is any better alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

use [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#server-access-logging-overview)

don't use DynamoDB, if you need to query the logs in the target bucket setup [Spectrum](https://blog.panoply.io/the-spectrum-of-redshift-athena-and-s3) to query the logs which are also in S3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [S3 Access Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)?

And configure event based on new records in log bucket. However, this logs will not tell you if user has finished download or not.